# ExtJS form handling array fields

Tags: arrays, forms, extjs

I have a model that contains an array of int. I want to display a form that can edit this array of int.

```
// Form definition
var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    items: [
    /* .. */
    ]
});

form.loadRecord(record);
```

`record.states` is an array of `int`, for example: `[2, 7]`

For the form I tried two ways, but none works as I expect.

**1st way**:

```
var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    items: [{
       xtype: 'combo',
       fieldLabel: 'States',
       name: 'states',
       multiSelect: true,
       store: [[1, 'Alabama'], [2, 'California'], [3, 'New York'], [7, 'Georgia']]
    }]
});
```

Problems are:

- When I submit the form, the selected data are sent with name `states` and I want `states[]` to fit with my php back-end
- the `loadRecord` doesn't work and just display `2, 7` and doesn't pre-select the item in the combo (here California and Georgia)

**2nd way**:

```
var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    items: [{
       xtype: 'combo',
       fieldLabel: 'States',
       name: 'states[]',
       multiSelect: true,
       store: [[1, 'Alabama'], [2, 'California'], [3, 'New York'], [7, 'Georgia']]
    }]
});
```

Problem is:

- The `loadRecord` doesn't do anything, the combo stays empty.

I am sure this is some common behavior that I am missing, can someone please point me in the right direction ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure how to do that

```
var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    items: [{
        xtype: 'combo',
        fieldLabel: 'States',
        name: 'states[]',
        multiSelect: true,
        store: [[1, 'Alabama'], [2, 'California'], [3, 'New York'], [7, 'Georgia']],
        value: record.states
    }]
});
```

I don't use the `loadRecord` and set directly the value in the field definition. Also you have to be sure that the the values as the same type as the store keys. I had to do

```
value: record.states.map(function(v) { return parseInt(v); })
```

because my array was an array of string.

This link is useful: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?149501-Can-t-populating-MultiSelect-control-from-JSON-Store&p=656165&viewfull=1#post656165